# CaseInsensitive Socket.io in() method

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
io.sockets.in(text).emit("Data",data);
```

How can I make socket.io to compare the rooms in sockets without considering the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a line to convert the `text` variable to lower case.

```
var lowerCaseText = text.toLowerCase();
io.sockets.in(lowerCaseText).emit("Data",data);
```